# Bing chat scrapper

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

trying to scrape answers from bing chat,but has some errors

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium_stealth import stealth



options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension(r"D:\chromext\extension_1_0_5_0.crx")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\chrome driver\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
     "source": """
          const newProto = navigator.__proto__
          delete newProto.webdriver
          navigator.__proto__ = newProto
          """
    })
stealth(driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )


driver.get('https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&id=264960&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fsecure%2fPassport.aspx%3fedge_suppress_profile_switch%3d1%26requrl%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fwww.bing.com%252fsearch%253ftoWww%253d1%2526redig%253dCF6FAA3B24AB4DB69ADB641F4381D432%2526q%253dBing%252bAI%2526showconv%253d1%2526wlexpsignin%253d1%26sig%3d300479B8A0DF658D00BB6B57A1CD6457&wp=MBI_SSL&lc=1033&CSRFToken=1df1d208-abf2-4cf1-98c8-b17e091b4dd1&aadredir=1')
mail = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0116"]')
mail.send_keys('pasw')
mail.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sleep(2)
pasw = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0118"]')
pasw.send_keys('login')
pasw.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="iLandingViewAction"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]').click()
sleep(3)
driver.get('https://www.bing.com/search?toWww=1&redig=AD6EA0F2A6224B5989B5A577FCFB4100&q=Bing+AI&showconv=1')
sleep(5)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)   
inp = driver.find_element_by_class_name('b_searchbox')
inp.click()
inp.send_keys('hi, are you better than chatgpt?')
inp.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
# ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
sleep(1000)
```

has error in inp.click: element not interactable
I'm view html code and textarea has a class b_searchbox, but has an error element not interactable
trying to find by xpath or id, but has the same, maybe someone scrape bing chat using selenium beofre, how you do that?

Answer (score 0):

i'm doing something like that, but i just used the Xpath, like this:

```
BingUrl = 'https://www.bing.com/search?q=Bing+AI&showconv=1&FORM=hpcodx'
edgDriver = webdriver.Edge()
edgDriver.get(BingUrl)
time.sleep(15)
TextArea_Xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/cib-serp//cib-action-bar//div/div[2]/div[2]/cib-text-input//form/label/textarea'
TextArea = edgDriver.find_element(By.XPATH, TextArea_Xpath)
Mensaje = Last_Message()
time.sleep(5)
TextArea.click()
pyautogui.write(Mensaje)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

I'm doing this with edge, and sorry if you can't understand me, my english isn't good haha.

PD: TextArea isn't enabled to use .send_keys(), i really don't kwnow why, so i used .click(), and pyautogui to send the message

i'm really not an expert but it works